# How to get the exact value of an input when parent div clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Assuming the code below was rowed out from the database  having everything the same except the value how do I get the value of any one clicked without affecting the others?

```
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="r">Home</span></a> 
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" value="123">
</div>    
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="t">Create User</span></a> 
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" name="rank" value="abc">
</div> 
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="t">List Users</span></a>
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" name="rank" value="abc">
</div>   
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="t">Admin</span></a> 
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" name="rank" value="abc">
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming you want to use jQuery, research https://api.jquery.com/click, https://api.jquery.com/find and https://api.jquery.com/val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JS, ES6

- find elements by classname in the document
- for each one of the elements attach onclick
- once inside onclick find elements by tag name in this element
- use first one to get value

```js
let minds = document.getElementsByClassName('mind');

[...minds].forEach(x => {
  x.onclick = () => {
    let i = x.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0];
    console.log(i.value)
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="r">Home</span></a>
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" value="123">
</div>
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="t">Create User</span></a>
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" name="rank" value="abc1">
</div>
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="t">List Users</span></a>
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" name="rank" value="abc2">
</div>
<div class="mind">
  <a href="#"><span class="t">Admin</span></a>
  <input class="input1" type="hidden" name="rank" value="abc3">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it safe the day should ask the question for long i would have safe time